# Accessing a CollectionViewSource in a ResourceDirectory from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, code-behind

I have a `DataGrid` where users can insert new data.  If the user decides not to proceed with saving the new row, they cancel the addition and the data remains as when the record was opened.  To fix this I have worked out I need (I'm pretty sure, at least) to clear the grid and then refresh it.

However, my data is bound to a `CollectionViewSource` in a `ResourceDictionary` and the `DataGrid`'s ItemsSource is a property of that CVS, and I can't get to it in code-behind.

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="../AllStyles.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="AuditCollectionSource.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dgridManagementIssues" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AuditManagementIssues, Mode=TwoWay}" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...

  <Button Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Click="btnCancel_Click" />
```

So, when the cancel button is clicked, I get the ItemsSource from the DataGrid and clear it.  Then I want to set it to the 'AuditManagementIssues' `ItemsSource`:

cs:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // clear the grid
    ObservableCollection<AuditManagementIssue> issues = new ObservableCollection<AuditManagementIssue>();
    dgridManagementIssues.ItemsSource = issues;
    issues.Clear();
    // repopulate the grid
// reload the model?
    lGFinanceEntities.Entry<AuditStatement>(currentAuditStatement).Reload();
    dgridManagementIssues.ItemsSource = AuditManagementIssues;  <-- can't do this
}
```

The intellisense tells me The name 'AuditManagementIssues' does not exist in the current context.

When the window is closed and opened again, all the data is where it should be.

So, how do I refresh/reload the data from code-behind?  Or, is there a better way to remove items that have been entered but not saved to the `DataGrid`.

Comment: With a datagrid, you're best not allowing users to edit directly in it. Give them a child view as an overlay that they edit or add. Give them a clone or copy to edit. This way you can validate and when it fails you just do nothing with the object they're editing. If they abandon editing then the object is never in your collection so you don't need to remove the thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's logically, that `AuditManagementIssues` does not exist in the current context, because it is `Path` in `Binding`. So you can set `Binding` for the `ItemsSource` of `dgridManagementIssues` again:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(dgridManagementIssues, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("AuditManagementIssues") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

**If you don't set ItemsSource to new value**, you can update the bindig from code behind:

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(dgridManagementIssues, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty)?.UpdateTarget();
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code as it stands, you could ensure you're binding to a CollectionView rather than just a CollectionViewSource.
CollectionView has a Refresh method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx

You could grab a collectionviewsource out a window's resources and get it's default view then refresh it using code something like:

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = this.Resources["AuditManagementIssues"] as CollectionViewSource;
var lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(cvs);
lcv.Refresh();
```